# What is the correct word for 'worrylessly'?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

What would be the appropriate word for worrylessly in this following context 
"I shall prefer him for this task. And [worrylessly] expect an amazing result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct word would only have one y: "worrilessly." While "worrilessly" may not be in your dictionary, "worriless" certainly is. It's proforma that an adverb can be made of any adjective that was original formed from a verb by adding "ly."  Since the adjective "worriless" was formed from the verb "worry," you can add "ly" and have it be a legitimate adverb.

The dictionary doesn't list all modifiers that are formed from adding suffixes to verbs.  For example, you can add "ed" and "ing" to any verb to form a modifier, but the large majority of dictionary definitions for verbs don't list *verb*+"ing" or *verb*+"ed" as modifiers, just like many don't list formations from adding "ly." Only those most commonly used are in the dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

"I shall prefer him for this task. And ***confidently*** expect (an) amazing result."

If *confidently* seems too sure of itself, and *worrilessly* and *unworriedly* are uncomfortably unfamiliar neologisms, perhaps '***calmly***'.

Also, I would probably say '*anticipate*' rather than '*expect*'.

Comment: Stepping of first base doesn't put a player on second.  There's a whole base line to run.  So being worriless won't make anyone confident, just without worry.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman - fair point.  I've edited.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the context in the question, there are a few adverbs that could be used in the context. For example:

[**Unworriedly**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unworriedly):

> In an unworried way; **calmly**, without anxiety.

[Wiktionary]

The adverb **calmly** could be a candidate.

Now, the issue is how the adverb *unworriedly* could be used idiomatically in your context. This adverb is not broadly used even though it could get the message across. If your context means you are *without worry* in terms of his performing his task successfully, you could consider more idiomatic adverbs such as *undoubtedly* or *confidently* (as suggested by Dan).

[**Undoubtedly**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/undoubtedly):

> Without doubt; certainly:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Contrasting "unworriedly expect amazing results" with "undoubtedly/confidently expect amazing results", the latter is more idiomatic. I agree with Dan that to anticipate is better than to expect.

Comment: I like *calmly* - *worrilessly* and *unworriedly* are very unfamiliar and awkward-sounding.  Not wrong, but hardly everyday words.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. I upvoted your post after you edited it. :-)

Comment: And I've reinstated a preference for *anticipate* over *expect* after reading your post! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could say ***[nonchalantly](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nonchalant)***

> (adj.) coolly unconcerned, indifferent, or unexcited; casual

[Dictionary.com]

**Usage:**

"I shall prefer him for this task. And **nonchalantly** expect amazing result(s)."

Comment: You *could*, but does that sound like something someone would actually say?

Answer (score 0):

You might use 'blithely':

> **blithe**
>   *adj.* blither, blithest
>   1. Carefree and lighthearted.
>   ....
>   **blithe′ly** *adv.*
>   **blithe′ness** *n.*

[blithely. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved January 10 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blithely .]

In your example,

> I shall prefer him for this task, and **blithely** expect an amazing result.